# The loc function in jupyter does not work for filtering my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pandas-loc

I am pretty new to Jupyter and have imported a data set. That worked fine. Then I wanted to use the `loc` function to get just one specific value in a specific column. However the `loc` function simply doesn't work on my Jupyter notebook. I have restarted the whole system - still doesn't work.

Here is an image of the imported data and the DataFrame:

[image]

Then I tried the loc function, however - nothing changes in the DataFrame. It actually should filter in the column "Type 1" to just contain values "Fire":

[image]

Can someone please help me to get this working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please do not post images of a DataFrame. It would be better to post your DataFrame in a table or as code block. To your question. Your code works find, but the `df` at the end of your seconde qic prints out the whole dataframe. Write `df.loc[df['Type 1']=='Fire']` in the last line of a block and you will get your result. Or make an asignment `df = df.loc[df['Type 1']=='Fire']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a simple mistake.
df prints the whole dataframe just remove the last line

```
!pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/content/pokemon.csv")
df.head(10)
df.loc[df["Type 1"] == "Fire"]
```